# Possible to move Core Plot piechart labels?

Tags: ios, label, core-plot, pie-chart

I am using Core Plots version 1.2 and I would like to have the labels for each section of the chart to move closer to the center of it. How do I do this?

Comment: Which labels? The graph title? Axis labels? Axis tick labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
CPTPieChart *pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
pieChart.labelOffset = 0.0f;
```

the CPTPieChart has a "labelOffset" values that moves the pie-chart wedge labels closer to or farther away from the center of the pie chart. The bigger the value of labelOffset the farther from the center.